# XDebug, how to avoid to stop in the index.php everytime?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug

I have Netbeans with CodeIgniter and Xdebug.

Every time it stops on the index.php in a loop. It is quite slow to click go forward one step every time. Is there a way to make it run until it finds a break point?

Comment: There will be an option when you setup the debug that requests it to stop on first line. Unset that and you will be away.

Comment: See the first checkbox in this picture - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#options. Untick it

Comment: Now, i feel like an idiot. Yes, the option avoid the continue execute of the code. Thanks guys.

Comment: I'd rather to answer the question :). After all 22 people see the question and probably they found it useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was simple, thanks to @RiggsFolly and @Phil. You need to go to

Tools > Options > Choose Php > Debugging Tab, and deselect the: **Stop at First Line**.

[image]